# Fink Java REST API Client Submit Job with Basic Auth

Tags: apache-flink

The official Flink documentation tells that if you want to secure Job Manager REST API - you need to put a reverse proxy (e.g. Nginx) in front of it and configure auth there.

It's not the issue.
The issue, though, is how to instruct Flink RestClient (from flink-runtime lib) to send BASIC Auth header. I analyzed the code - it simply doesn't allow you to customize a job submission request.

Has anyone faced similar issue? As a last resort I can always create my own HTTP client to talk to Job Manager REST API but this looks ridiculous.

Any help appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Like you mentioned in the documentation, there is no support for this in Flink itself, hence you need to put something like a reverse proxy in front of it.

Comment: It's not a question about reverse proxy. It's a question of how to bypass BASIC Auth HTTP header to Flink RestClient in Flink Java Client SDK.

Comment: You would have to fork Flink, add the code yourself and then build and run your fork yourself.